# Why does the representation of the filter matter? How explain it to people outside signal processing theory?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Recently I was able to solve a problem on concerning filtering by changing the representation from zero-pole-gain to 2nd-order-section when dealing with higher sampling rate data.

But: What do representations do to the function of the filter? Why did this work?

Comment: Why don't you show what you did? "Changing representation" doesn't mean much, there's something you did that you haven't mentionned.

Comment: No, actually, really, the whole point was to keep all parameters of the filter the same, but adapt it to data obtained with different sampling-rate... it was proposed to me to use 2nd order section and that's all that was necessary to make the filter work (it was eliminating the signal instead of filtering it, when applied in the first-order).

Comment: That was the original representation:
Nyquist = SR/2 
passband_lowpass = 16/Nyquist 
stopband_lowpass = 35/Nyquist 
passband_highpass = 5/Nyquist 
stopband_highpass = 3/Nyquist 
[order,nfreq] = buttord(passband_lowpass,stopband_lowpass,1.5,30) 
[order2,nfreq2] = buttord(passband_highpass,stopband_highpass,1.5,30)
[b,a] = butter(order,nfreq,'low'); 
[c,d] = butter(order2,nfreq2,'high') 
sleepeeg = filter(b,a,sleepeeg) 
sleepeeg = filter(c,d,sleepeeg)

Comment: This was the advice I followed to change the representation: SR=1024; Nyquist=SR/2; Wp = [5 16]/Nyquist; Ws = [3 35]/Nyquist; Rp = 1.5; Rs = 30; [n,Wn] = buttord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs); [z,p,k] = butter(n,Wn); sos = zp2sos(z,p,k); sleepeeg=sleepeeg-mean(sleepeeg); y=sosfilt(sos,sleepeeg); (well that was the advice I followed back then that made it work).

Comment: @IvoBulgermansky your comments are pretty much unreadable code. Please add that code to your question by hitting the "edit" button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that each for each structure there is a different sensitivity to small perturbations of the coefficients. The locus of poles and zeros change under those perturbations.

The different forms correspond to different factorizations of the polynomials that correspond to the filters transfer function.

So with infinite precision arithmetic the different forms are exactly equivalent but the factorizations are not equivalent with respect to small perturbations.

Similar ideas are found in numerical linear algebra. A Cholesky factorization is more accurate than the unfactored matrix the factorization corresponds to.  This is why rank one updates are favored in various algorithms

Comment: Pan Pawlukiewicz, dziekuje bardzo. Sounds like the kind of answer I need, but will need to understand in more detail... something that ties back to the simple 2-dimensional attributes (amplitude, frequency) of the signal, which is unfortunately my level of understanding... I know that filters selectively attenuate the amplitude of specific sine/cosine components in the signal, but I don't know what zeros and poles are, what a factorization is... I have a bit of a guess what the role of the polynomial is (to assign component specific attenuations, based on an equation with several unknowns?).

Comment: I realize now you probably are not native Polish, so... dziekuje bardzo = thank you dearly :)

Comment: my parents were born in Poland but in my mother’s case what was Poland and despite their best efforts my Polish language is limited. I do retain the tendency to over consume alcohol.